# deploy the project again with new app on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I happened to delete the app that I configured with my project on GitHub. Now when I'm trying to deploy the project with an app in another Heroku account, it's showing this:
$ git push heroku
remote: !       No such app as agile-atoll-98419.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-atoll-98419.git/' not found

and

$ heroku open
 !    Couldn't find that app.

Please guide

Comment: I'm assuming there is a correlation between deleting the app and Heroku not being able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the previous remote:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Then add it with the new app name:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/<app name>.git
```

Further pushes will happen on your new app instead of the old one.

Alternatively for next time, if you remove the remote first, `heroku create` will set the new remote for easier pushing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I checked the config file in my project and then changed it url to the name of the newly created app on heroku. Then after running it. It worked.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as resolved then? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

first You need to remove the previous remote:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Then add it with the new app Name

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/<your created app name>.git
```

example: `git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/barishal-gadget-store.git`

Flow this image :[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSXwE.png)